# I have a problem with npm, more precisely with quick.db

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js, quick.db

> npm i quick.db

```
better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\Clays v2.0\node_modules\better-sqlite3
prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.15.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release
node-gyp rebuild --release

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Users\�ukasz.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
gyp ERR! stack at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
gyp ERR! stack at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Łukasz\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\Clays v2.0\node_modules\better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\Clays v2.0\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild --release

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-23T08_21_59_641Z-debug.log
npm WARN Invalid version: "0.1"
npm WARN Clays v2.0 No description
npm WARN Clays v2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN Clays v2.0 No README data
npm WARN Clays v2.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install: prebuild-install || npm run build-release
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-23T08_21_59_893Z-debug.log
```

Above I gave an error while installing quick.db. Does anyone have a way to solve it?

Comment: Look into the log files that are mentioned in the error output.

Comment: Run CMD as admin and type `npm install -g windows-build-tools`. Then try your install command again.